# Apache rewrite/redirect directory to querystring

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I plan on learning the ins and outs of mod_rewrite, but I have a problem I would like solved before I get around to doing that, and I'm probably only missing something small here anyway.

I want to force redirect any directory that contains digits `[0-9]{1,4}` to a single php file with a querystring of that number.

For example

```
http://example.com/23
```

or

```
http://example.com/23/
```

would redirect to:

```
http://example.com?23
```

(the .php file is my index)

Currently I have the following:

```
RewriteCond  $/([0-9]{1,4})/^
RewriteRule  $/([0-9]+)^ ?%1 [R]
```

Which throws a `500`...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 'twas just a syntax error, which I fixed, and the result didn't work...
This also didn't work:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /?$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,4})$ ?$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,4})$ ?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Seems to be working (the URLs no longer 404, they're sent to the index.php), I'll just check if the querystring is still being passes via php and I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Yup, worked like a charm. To think I was only a couple of characters off with my second guess... Thanks.

Comment: Very odd exception... Everything works except the instance of `1`. Im testing the site in a folder, let's say `http://domain.com/folder/`, and clicking a link `http://domain.com/folder/21` works, redirecting to `http://domain.com/folder/?21`, all numbers work except one, which redirects to `http://domain.com/1/` instead of `http://domain.com/folder/?1`... Very strange....

Comment: Is there a folder or file called `1`?

Comment: no... well there is a `1.jpg`, but the same goes for all numbers, so it shouldn't make a difference.